# Can't Send Command from Arduino to Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, arduino

I can control Arduino From Flash its working fine for me as attached but I need to make it reverse,
I need to control the flash from Arduino if I press the push button (pin13) in the flash it will gotoAndStop Frame (2) or (1). Please help Thanks

here is all the source file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PvoD41Is8_gcl5bJpVWlhqtvre3twENK/view?usp=sharing

working video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Z2onMf301p5DHEFhetYEXKrjMQAKAWP/view?usp=sharing

**Arduino Connection Code Working fine**

```
import flash.net.Socket;

var _socket:Socket = new Socket();
var _proxyAddress:String = "127.0.0.1";
var _proxyPort:uint = 5331;
_socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
_socket.connect(_proxyAddress, _proxyPort);
      
function onConnect(event:Event):void{
        trace("Socket Connected");
    }
```

**Flash Code for Arduino on and off**

```
Frame 1
MovieClip(root)._socket.writeUTFBytes("f");
MovieClip(root)._socket.flush();

Frame 2
MovieClip(root)._socket.writeUTFBytes("n");
MovieClip(root)._socket.flush();
```

**Flash Button Code**

```
onBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,btn1);
function btn1(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
}

offBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,btn2);
function btn2(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

**Arduino Code**

```
#define BULB 13
int incoming = LOW;

void setup(){
Serial.begin(57600);
Serial.println("INITALIZING");
pinMode(BULB, OUTPUT);
Serial.println("READY");
}

void loop(){
  
if(Serial.available () > LOW ){
incoming = Serial.read();

if(incoming == 'n'){
digitalWrite(BULB, LOW);
}
else if(incoming == 'f'){
digitalWrite(BULB, HIGH);
}

  }
}
```

Comment: So, what;s the problem? You don't have any code that is supposed to wait for and then read date from the socket. You can start with the official example: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html

Comment: @MohtadeenMastoor If I understand correctly, you'd like to "reverse" the logic of the code, so instead of controlling an LED on the Arduino from Actionscript, you read a button state on the same Arduino pin and control a frame via Actionscript. If that's the case, I've provided an update which hopefully provides useful info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been more than a decade since I used actionscript and I no longer have Flash license, so unfortunately I won't be able to replicate your setup.

That being said, I might have a few hopefully helpful pointers:

Double check serproxy.cfg is properly configured.
Your serproxy.cfg file is configured to connect to an Arduino via Windows on port `COM4` with baudrate `57600`. Double check:

- the port and buad rate match
- the device is connected via USB
- the port isn't busy/already open in Arduino's Serial Monitor (or other tools reading/writing to the same COM port)

When I last used serproxy I was using OSX and had to configure `serial_device` instead of `comm_ports`. Not 100% sure this will work, but if COM4 is indeed your Arduino's port, you can try settings `serial_device=COM4`.

I am not sure why, but not all serproxy downloads worked for me.
I had luck with the version that shipped with [as3glue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/as3glue/downloads).
(FWIW, you can also check out my [Arduino & Actionscript](https://lifesine.eu/talks/arduino/arduino_and_actionscript.zip) talk resources from 2010. It does not include serproxy, but does have a few Arduino/Flash examples and hopefully helpful slides).

Personally, as much as I've enjoyed actionscript, I'd recommend switching languages given Flash Player is no longer supported.

The closest syntax I can think of is javascript and [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) is a creative friendly library. Its drawing functions (`rect()`, `image()`, etc.) as well as DOM (e.g. [`createButton()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createButton))) should help reacreate your buttons (`onBtn`, `offBtn`).

In terms of serial control, you can use the [p5.serialport](https://github.com/p5-serial/p5.serialport) library.
It uses [p5.serialcontrol](https://github.com/p5-serial/p5.serialcontrol/releases) similar to `serproxy` (but using WebSockets instead of raw TCP sockets). Once you've configured your serial port correctly you can start adapting their [`writeExample`](https://github.com/p5-serial/p5.serialport/blob/main/examples/08-writeExample/sketch.js).
It [writes 'L'/'H'](https://github.com/p5-serial/p5.serialport/blob/main/examples/08-writeExample/sketch.js#L113), you can `'n'`,`'f'` and use two buttons instead of `mousePressed()`.

(If you're feeling more adventurous you can try Python and [pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports) instead. The syntax is quite different from actionscript, but also a lot less verbose. For the UI, if it's just two buttons the [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) might suffice, otherwise there are plenty of other snazzy GUI libraries such as [kivy](https://kivy.org/))

**Update** Viewing your video and Re-reading your question made this section stand out:

> I need to make it reverse, I need to control the flash from Arduino
> if I press the push button (pin13) in the flash it will gotoAndStop
> Frame (2) or (1).

The first step is to change the Arduino code so it reads a button instead of lighting an LED:

- change `pinMode(13, INPUT)`
- use [`digitalRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalread/) instead of `digitalWrite()`
- one idea is to simply write a single byte: a `1` or a `0` depending on the button pin state (returned by `digitalRead()`).

Here's a basic example:

```cpp
#define BUTTON 13

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(57600);
    pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
    Serial.write(digitalRead(BUTTON));
    // wait 40ms ~= 25fps
    delay(40);
}
```

**Note:**

- `Serial.write` is not the same as `Serial.println()`: it doesn't send a string nor the end line character (`\n`). Be aware you might not see this character in Serial Monitor as plain ASCII, but it should be visible as hex. (for example [CoolTerm](https://freeware.the-meiers.org/) has this feature)
- `delay()` is added to not flood serial too many messages too often (limiting output to ~25fps)
- this sketch is `continuously` outputing button state: you may want to "debounce": check if the state has changed (from off to on or the reverse) to only send a serial message when the state changed

Here's a basic example demonstrating debouncing:

```cpp
#define BUTTON 13

bool wasOn, isOn;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(57600);
    pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
    isOn = digitalRead(BUTTON);

    if(!wasOn && isOn){
        wasOn = true;
        Serial.write(1);
    }
    if(wasOn && !isOn){
        wasOn = false;
        Serial.write(0);
    }
    // wait 40ms ~= 25fps
    delay(40);
}
```

The above code isn't tested with an Arduino, so it may require testing debugging. (CoolTerm's hex view will be useful).

The other thing you might need to double check is `digitalRead()` returns `1` if the button is pressed or `0` (and adjust what `Serial.write` if the expected state appears flipped in actionscript).
Alternatively change the `gotoAndStop()` frame in actionscript.

Regarding as3 code, you might need to use [`Socket`'s `socketData` event](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#event:socketData) and [`readBoolean()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#readBoolean()).
Again, without Flash installed, this is untested, but hopefully a useful guide towards how you might to implement this (meaning debugging/tweaking may be required):

```js
import flash.net.Socket;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

var _socket:Socket = new Socket();
var _proxyAddress:String = "127.0.0.1";
var _proxyPort:uint = 5331;
_socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
// listen to incoming Arduino data
_socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);
_socket.connect(_proxyAddress, _proxyPort);
      
function onConnect(event:Event):void{
    trace("Socket Connected");
}
// called when new Arduino data arrives
function onData(event:ProgressEvent):void{
    // read the 1 or 0 from Arduino
    var isOn:Boolean = _socket.readBoolean();
    // print received data
    trace("arduino data event", event, "isOn =",isOn);
    // change frames according to received boolean value 
    if(isOn){
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }else{
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I am getting below error
Scene 1, Layer 'Arduino Connection', Frame 1, Line 2, Column 17 1172: Definition flash.net:Event could not be found.
Scene 1, Layer 'Arduino Connection', Frame 1, Line 3, Column 17 1172: Definition flash.net:ProgressEvent could not be found.
Scene 1, Layer 'Arduino Connection', Frame 1, Line 2, Column 17 1172: Definition flash.net:Event could not be found.
Scene 1, Layer 'Arduino Connection', Frame 1, Line 3, Column 17 1172: Definition flash.net:ProgressEvent could not be found.

Comment: yeahhh! 
I am getting the below error but the movie clip is working and the push button also working now 
Scene 1, Layer 'Arduino Connection', Frame 1, Line 17, Column 10 Warning: 1090: Migration issue: The onData event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in ActionScript 3.0.  You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ( 'data', callback_handler).

Comment: **screenshot**
https://paste.pics/JMY4C

Comment: Not bad! It's a warning, not an error: it does not stop the code from running. 
I see one arduino data event traced in the output windows: that's positive!
Does it trigger consistently ? (e.g. whenever the button state changed ?)
(I've made a minor tweak to trace the `isOn` value as well in the code above: you can try it). Hopefully, despite the warning, the code will still run and send a socket data event each time ther's a button state change

Comment: screenShot
https://paste.pics/JN9DV
The button is working like when pressed light on when leaving the button light off movie clip

Comment: Nice! The output window suggests this works. Currently I can only see one frame, so can't tell if the frame matches the button state as you intent, but if it doesn't simply swap `if(isOn)` for `if(!isOn)` to swap the `gotoAndStop` frames. Based on the output window what you're trying to achieve is pretty much there: the Arduino firmware sends the button state (debounced, doesn't flood with constant message of the same state) and and you can get the boolean state in actionscript. You can control timeline or anything you need in Flash from using your Arduino button ! Have fun!

Comment: One last comment: I noticed your Flash Project is targetting Adobe AIR. I haven't tried it myself, but the [as3-arduino-connector AIR Native Extension](https://github.com/quetwo/as3-arduino-connector) looks interesting. It should allow you to connect to the Arduino without needing serproxy, but will require more in depth knowledge of actionscript 3.0/Adobe AIR. A completely different approach is to switch the Arduino to a WiFi microcontroller like ESP32 and set it up either as a Websocket server (using as as3.0 WebSocket client library), HTTP REST Server using the built-in flash.net.URLLoader

Comment: ... or even OSC (using an Adobe AIR OSC library (based on UDP (Datagram) sockets)). HTH

Comment: You are right but I am not good in As3 + Arduino both:( now I need to keep two button same as flash movie clip for on separate button and for off separate

Comment: That's ok, I remember it took me a few good hours to teach myself the Arduino blink tutorial a while ago. These days at least there are a lot more resources available. Don't worry too much about about not being good: gotta start somewhere! Just need to keep going, at your own pace. The comments are getting lengthy, which is not recommended on this site. If the answer was helpful consider [voting/marking with the checking mark if it solved your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I recommend posting another question linking to this one, focusing on two buttons.

Comment: ...as a starter, you might need to get comfortable with binary.
You've already sent a single bit (on/off), but now you need to send a byte, of which you'll only use the first two bits: one for each button. (e.g. both buttons off = 0, 1st button on, second button off = 1, 1st button off, second button on = 2, both buttons on = 3). You can easily visualise this in Windows Calculator set to Programmer view and 
using the bit toggling keypad: toggle the last 2 zeros (representing button states) and notice both binary (BIN) and decimal (DEC) values in the top left. You then update arduino code.

Comment: ...you've already used `pinMode()` to setup one button as `INPUT`: do the same for the second button, replicate the `digitalRead()` logic, as well as debouncing (you'll need two boolean vars per button (e.g. `bool was1On, is1On, was2On, is2On;`). The catch is you'll use a byte to store the state of both buttons and you can use [`bitSet()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/bits-and-bytes/bitset/) to set each button's bit. Once that's done, you can write it to serial (and test it too!). In as3.0 you need to swap `readBoolean()` with `readByte()` and you'll also...

Comment: ...need to take into account it's [`readByte()`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#readByte()) range (e.g. -127 to 127, not 0-255), so might need ` something like `var buttonStates:int = _socket.readBoolean() & 255;` to mask (lookup bit masking) and get back to 0-255 range. After that point, you can either read each bit so use a `switch` statement to handle the 4 states (2 per button).

Comment: Hi George, you should see this video of your effort result
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16EXjT_WW_YZY50-TOPSiEs6ccg-9ssn8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is awesome ! Thanks for sharing ! You're getting the hang of it: Nicely done Mohtadeen !

Comment: Hi, one more question currently I am sending numbers from Arduino to flash like Serial.write(1);.
how can I send the character like (abc or yes no)?

Comment: Reading the [as3 Socket docs](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#readUTF()) looks like `readUTF()` could do what you need with a caveat: "The string is assumed to be prefixed with an unsigned short integer that indicates the length in bytes." (which translates to need to do something like `Serial.write(2);Serial.write("no");` (because "no" has two characters) or `Serial.write(3);Serial.write("yes");` (because "yes" has three characters) to prefix the string you're writing with the number of characters to be read in as3. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've just noticed there's `readUnsignedByte` which reads a single byte, but already in the 0-255 range. This may be more difficult to pull off in as3, but not impossible: You would use `Serial.println("yes");` / `Serial.println("no");` which also appends the line feed (`\n`) at the end. Then in as3 you'd have a boolean to check if the current character received (via `readUnsignedByte` is `\n` (decimal value 10, see ASCII table)) or not.
If the current char isn't `\n` (e.g. byte to char via https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#fromCharCode()), append

Comment: @MohtadeenMastoor I found [this Arduino example](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/communication/SerialEvent). It illustrates the idea mentioned above of buffering one character at a time into a string until `\n`: you'd need to write the as3 equivalent (using `readUnsignedByte()` / `String.fromCharCode`). I'd try a basic Arduino sketch sending `Serial.write(3);Serial.write("yes");` first and using `trace(_socket.readUTF());` in `onData` first. Good luck!